# youtube.d.ts File for the youtube-iframe-api to use in Angular 2 needed

Tags: angular, typescript, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I try to use the [youtube iframe api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=de) for showing and controling video snippets with a smooth angular2 integration. And respecting the type concept of typescript is important to the webpack compiler and me :).

### The quick setup of my tests:

use  [@angular/cli](https://cli.angular.io/) (Version 1.0.0-beta.32.3) to setup and install the [ng2-youtube-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-youtube-player) and then two small adjustments:

```
ng new test002
cd test002
npm install ng2-youtube-player --save-dev
```

The app.module was extended according to [ng2-youtube-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-youtube-player), but in the app.component I had a small correction and an error:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',// app renamed to app-root
    template: `
        <youtube-player
      [videoId]="id"
      (ready)="savePlayer($event)"
      (change)="onStateChange($event)"
    ></youtube-player>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
  player: YT.Player;// Error: Cannot find namespace 'YT'
  private id: string = 'qDuKsiwS5xw';

    savePlayer (player) {
    this.player = player;
    console.log('player instance', player)
    }
  onStateChange(event){
    console.log('player state', event.data);
  }
}
```

For the error I faked the namespace with a youtube.d.ts file:

```
// dummy namespace...
export as namespace YT;

export interface Player {
    name: string;
    length: number;
    extras?: string[];
}
```

Now using ng serve the webpack is compiling without error, even if there is YT unknown within the [ng2-youtube-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-youtube-player) package.

My question after intensive search on the internet: Can someone may provide a correct .d.ts file or tell me how to find out?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This installs the TypeScript types for the YouTube `iframe`:

Using Yarn:

```
yarn add @types/youtube
```

Or NPM:

```
npm install @types/youtube
```

As @TaeKwonJoe points out below, with `@types/youtube` installed, add the following to your project `tsconfig.json` under `compilerOptions`:

```
"typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types"
],
"types": [ "youtube" ]
```

Comment: The YT namespace is defined by the `@types/youtube` package, what I've searched for, Thanks. The `youtube` package contains a different interface specially to upload youtube videos (if I read the `node_modules/youtube/lib/youtube.js` right...).

Comment: For me just installing this package to the `devDependencies` worked. Maybe because it's 2022 right now and types in `node_modules/@types` are automatically used.

Answer (score 4):

As @Myonara stated, the accepted answer involved importing a youtube upload library which is extraneous to the actual solution.

Better yet:

1. Omit the npm youtube package from node_modules and package.json
2. Remove the line `import 'youtube';`
3. With @types/youtube installed, add the following to your project tsconfig.json under compilerOptions:

`"typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types"
],
"types": [ "youtube" ]`

The YT namespace will now be available.

```
playerStateChange(e) {
    switch (e.data) {
        case YT.PlayerState.PLAYING:
            console.debug('youtube playing');
            break;
        case YT.PlayerState.PAUSED:
            console.debug('youtube paused');
            break;
        case YT.PlayerState.ENDED:
            console.debug('youtube ended');
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for sharing! in step 3, in stead of add to `files` array, you can also just add `youtube` to the `types` array in tsconfig.json

Comment: This gives me `ERROR in No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule` :-/

Comment: @Simon_Weaver have you installed youtube types?
e.g. `npm install --save-dev @types/youtube`

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with this and trying a bunch of things. In the end adding `youtube` to [types in tsconfig.app.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) which fixed it.

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": ["youtube"]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

The only other thing I did was:

```
npm install @types/youtube
```

This allows me to freely use `new YT.Player(...)` without any other tricks (such as just calling `window['YT']` which I've seen.

If anybody can offer an explanation as to how my IDE (VS Code) can find it but the compiler can't I'm still curious!.

Answer (score 1):

```
/// <reference types="youtube" />
```

On the top of the file where you use YT namespace.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, `ng2-youtube-player` provides its own TypeScript definitions, which is nice. You can see them under `node_modules/ng2-youtube-player/ng2-youtube-player.d.ts`.

To use them, do something like this:

```
import { YoutubePlayer, YoutubePlayerService } from 'ng2-youtube-player';
```

And in your component class (assuming of course you know how to use `Zone`):

```
@ViewChild('myElement') ref: ElementRef;
service: YoutubePlayerService = new YoutubePlayerService(this.someZone);
player: YoutubePlayer = new YoutubePlayer(this.service, this.ref);
```

Comment: oh, yes, `node_modules/ng2-youtube-player/ng2-youtube-player.d.ts` is in the npm package and not in the github project for whatever reason. But it doesn't declare the YT stuff, which is in the example and the plugin doesn't provide the full parameter list to the player itself as described in [the youtube iframe api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=de) Thanks for mention the d.ts file in the package.

Comment: What are the "YT stuff", exactly? Which specific classes/types are you missing? Because the `Player` class you're referring to is almost certainly the declared `YoutubePlayer`.

Comment: Afaik is the symbol YT generated on DOM-root level by the script from `https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api` as described in [this original documentation from Google](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=de). The declared youtube player has only a subset of functionality, that's the reason I want to have the YT.d.ts file...

Comment: Okay, so I didn't realise you were actually looking for typings of the Youtube library itself. I don't think that was obvious from your post.

Comment: Actually, I just spent a minute looking at `ng2-youtube-player` and it simply wraps the API, so `YT.Player` becomes `YoutubePlayer`. Which missing functionality are you looking for?

Comment: I want to pass start/startSeconds or end/endSeconds as parameters, which I can already do in the iframe itself. Additionally I need the callback for the statusChange, in that I want to request the current position when it was paused or stopped. Potentially I have to code it in "pure" html/javascript first before I try an angular2 compliant way...