# onYouTubeIframeAPIReady on Angular2 can't find name 'YT'

Tags: angular, typescript, youtube-api, angular-cli, youtube-iframe-api

I'm trying to insert the YouTube embed API on my angular 2 project, built with angular cli.

I get a "can't find name 'YT'" when I try the approach commented on this question: [onYouTubeIframeAPIReady not firing on angular2 web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42868225/onyoutubeiframeapiready-not-firing-on-angular2-web-app#)

My service code looks like this:

```
loadAPI() {
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

(window as any).onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
  this.player = new YT.Player('player', {
    events: {
      'onReady': this.onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': this.onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
};

(window as any).onPlayerReady = function (event) {
  event.target.playVideo();
};

(window as any).onPlayerStateChange = function (status) {
  console.log(status.data);
};
```

I'm not sure where and how should I get the 'YT'structure. I know it comes from the "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api", but I have no idea of how to get angular to work this out.

Comment: Based from this [thread](https://github.com/orizens/ng2-youtube-player/issues/4), try to install the latest version. Run `npm i @types/youtube@0.0.28`. Then run `npm install --save`. Also, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42352944/youtube-d-ts-file-for-the-youtube-iframe-api-to-use-in-angular-2-needed), the YT namespace is defined by the `@types/youtube` package

Comment: Still no changes after installing @types/youtube. I've tried to add it to tsconfig.json, but had no success. The funny thing is, my text editor knows what 'YT' is, but the compiler doesn't.

Comment: @ArthurMuffinMadCaputo did you fix this? I have the same that my editor sees it but the compiler --prod build doesn't - even if I add `YT: any`

Answer (score -1):

Adding this to my imports for the file referencing YT seems to work.

```
import 'youtube';
```

Can someone please explain why! I realize this is similar to `import * from 'moment';` but I never really understood that either.